# Python - add new elements to xml without a root?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree, minidom

I need to make xml which has structure like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tag1 atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla'>
<tag2 atrib = 'something'>
<tag3 atrib = 'something'>
<tag4 atrib = '..'>
<tag5 atrib = 'important'><div><h1>ContentFrom **OldXml.xml** </h1></div>
...
```

is it possible to create it like this?
Since there is no root element defined (every element is the "root"), and I should just create element by element..

Any assistance would help,
Thanks!

Comment: You **must** have a root. It can be dummy like `<root></root>`

Comment: so it is not possible to generate doc with structure like mine?

Comment: It is possible - just make sure you wrap the elements with root

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you please give example

Comment: see my answer. I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below.

Assuming your data is in `data`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = [[1],['x','y'],['k',12,'zz']]

root = ET.Element("root")
for i,entry in enumerate(data):
  ET.SubElement(root,f'tag{i}',attrib={f'p{y}':str(v) for y,v in enumerate(entry)})
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <tag0 p0="1" />
   <tag1 p0="x" p1="y" />
   <tag2 p0="k" p1="12" p2="zz" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tag1 atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla'>
<tag2 atrib = 'something'>
<tag3 atrib = 'something'>
<tag4 atrib = '..'>
<tag5 atrib = 'important'><div><h1>ContentFrom **OldXml.xml** </h1></div>
```

This is not **XML document**, [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)

> A data object is an XML document if it is well-formed, as defined in
> this specification

and your example break following rules

> There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no
> part of which appears in the content of any other element.

and

> for each non-root element `C` in the document, there is one other
> element `P` in the document such that `C` is in the content of `P`,
> but is not in the content of any other element that is in the content
> of `P`.

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you think I can create it in the form of xml, with pretty print structure, and then in some way just remove spaces and have final format like this? Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, use whatever library you already use and put dummy root, then overload save/load function to change formatting - in this case to strip outermost dummy root.

Comment: not sure what you think exactly